# Other project's maven info artifacts via Maven API in code

Tags: java, maven-3

I want to get artifact information of an arbitrary  maven project. It could have multiple ways / profiles of being built (for example client jar, service app and front end war file, the way to build these will be with me, provided in a build.json file with in my own format, by the project maintainer.

Is there a way, to not build the project, nor make a plugin, but some how query maven, giving it the profile and the pom.xml as input, and getting the list of project artifacts of the package step? In some it could be the default jar, in others a war file but not with the artifact's name (over ridden output file name).

I know if I give the command

```
mvn package
```

I can parse the output and get the artifact name. Is there a way to get that thru code?

Want to get that war/ jar / final binary output file name(s) and  location after a build. Without parsing the text output of the mvn command - via a maven library call, if available? So in my "B-project" I can ask my "A-project" what is the location and file names of your output binary files. Which for example could be A-project/target/A-project-snapshot-1.jar or A-project/target/A-project-snapshot-1.war

Using Java code.

https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/

Comment: are you looking for [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)? or the same for another artifact?

Comment: @nullpointer no. when you say mvn package or mvn install at the end you generally get an artifact like if its a web app you get <some name>.war if its a library <some name>.jar most probably the output name is the maven project name + version like "MyProject-snapshot-0.0.1.war"

Comment: @nullpointer i want to get that war/ jar name and its location after a build. without parsing the text output of the mvn command - via a maven library call, if available? so in my "B-project" I can ask my "A-project" what is the location and file names of your output binary files.

Comment: And how do you consider the chances of people overriding the output directory path using something like [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/index.html) ?

Comment: I do not know how maven works. So are you saying a plugin can over write and the main API would not know the true location of the output artifacts? Anyway we can always work around that, for projects that do follow convention, let maven give me information. We already have a json file that projects can optionally add for other environment requirements, can add a optional object there for this information to be over riden. @nullpointer